# Is it posible integrate Socket.io with AWS Websockets Api Gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, aws-api-gateway

I have a Socket.io angular-client and nodejs-Server, when I connect directly there is not problem, but when I'm trying to use the AWS websocket api gateway it is not possible.

I deployed an EC2 instance to run the Socket.io server and in my laptop de Socket.io client with the example proposed [here](https://gist.github.com/luciopaiva/e6f60bd6e156714f0c5505c2be8e06d8). On direct connection everything works correctly but when I use the AWS Websockets Api Gateway it returns me

`engine.io-client:socket socket error [Circular] +858ms`

I implemented the route $connect as follows:

[image: $connect route implementation]

where ip_address corresponds to the public ip o f the EC2, I've also tried without the /socket.io, but nothing is working.

Am I miss configuring something in the route/integration? Or is not this the right way to work with socket.io and websockets api gateway